# How to invalidate the session in login page when the user clicks browser back button

Tags: jsp, session, spring-security

Hi guys I have done one mobile application ,where I have an issue with the browser back button, actually my problem is when the user tried to logged in with the credentials given, he will redirect to the menu page, when the user clicks browser back button the user session should invalidate, but in login page it is showing the credentails and again when I click the sumbit it is redirecting to the main page, I have googled a lot for this issue from the past 2 days, but I have no clue how this should be done, can you guys please help me. I tried keeping this script in login page

and this Meta tags in  of the jsp page

and also this in my controller.xml

Thanks

Rubina.

Comment: You can't invalidate the user session when the user clicks on the back button. Clicking the back button will not send any http request to your web server. It will just display the previous visited (cached) page from the browser's local history. Since in your case the last visited page is the login screen, it is perfectly normal that the user sees that along with the credentials he/she has previously entered. 

Unless i'm misinterpreting something, the behaviour of your application that you describe sounds quite normal. Could you elaborate what is your issue exactly?

Comment: In my application i have login page where i given custId and password as a credentials,when i click submit it is redirecting to main menu page again i click one of the menus i will redirect to the services,now when i click browser back button 2 times i will be in login page with credentials still in login page,i thought it is bug that not clearing the credentials.i have to redirect to the fresh login page when user clicks back button,sorry if there is any mistake in my english

Comment: Don't worry, it's not a bug. This is normal browser behaviour. The browser displays to the user the last visited page from the local browser history. It does not retrieve the page from your web server. It's not a security concern either.

Comment: ok thanks for your quick reply,but please help me is there any another way to do this ,i tested it with gmail after login when i click back button it is still in that same page.

Comment: if you dont want to allow user to go on login page when user clicked on back button, you can disable browser's back button.

Comment: can you please elobarate your answer Nnj,i tried all the way googled but any answer is not helpful for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys i found the solution to my problem.please keep this script in header of your login page

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function backButtonOverride()
{

  setTimeout("backButtonOverrideBody()", 1);

}

function backButtonOverrideBody()
{

  try {
    history.forward();
  } catch (e) {

  }

  setTimeout("backButtonOverrideBody()",50);
}
    </script>
```

and in body tag replace this

```
<body onLoad="backButtonOverride()">
```

this works fine for me in safari browser.thanks to stack over flow team

Comment: Friends this is tested with both safari browser and firefox,it works fine for me  ,in my sceario it is clearing the login credentials in login page and when i click on sub menu it is refreshing in the same page like gmail.may be it will be helpful for someone i am posting here

Answer (score 0):

See this page as a work-around to your problem: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/

You can see a demo of how this behaves here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/javascript-disable-browser-back-button/

What this does is that it shows the next visited page in the browser history, each time the user clicks on the back button. It has the effect that you are looking for. I suspect that this is also what gmail does.

Comment: lefty i have already seen this example and i tried to implement in my application,i kept the script and body attributes in my login page ,but there is no use of it,for your information i am using safari browser, i answered to my question above that works fine for the first time when i run my application,when i clear the server and run again it is not working,i am totally confused

Comment: I am also using safar and the demo page works fine. You must be doing something wrong. Check your code for typo's or similar errors.

Comment: Oh, check also that you don't have disabled javascript!

Comment: i am not disabling the javascript,can you please post the example page which is working for you,actually i kept the following code in login.jsp  ...<script language="JavaScript">

window.history.forward();
function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }</script> ........<body onload="noBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload=""> is this the correct way